# LazyColumn slow in samsung device in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I am using `LazyColumn` in my project and it is very slow on scrolling the items. I created a very small project to show what is the problem in my code. It scroll smoothy on `Pixel`, `OnePlus` devices, but it's laggy on `Samsung` device. So what are the things we can improve in this code.

**Problem**

You can see the scroll is laggy in [LazyColumn](https://youtube.com/shorts/M-8MNr7JkLw?feature=share).

[SeeAllView.kt](https://github.com/vivek-modi/LazyColumn/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/lazycolumn/SeeView.kt)

```
@Composable
fun SeeAllView(
    viewModel: MainActivityViewModel,
    handleItemSelection: (TestDataModel) -> Unit,
    ctaAction: (CurrentModel) -> Unit,
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp),
    ) {
        items(viewModel.itemList, key = { it.index }) { item ->
            ListContent(false, item, ctaAction, handleItemSelection)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListContent(
    useSpaceView: Boolean = true,
    myTestDataItem: TestDataModel,
    ctaAction: (CurrentModel) -> Unit,
    handleItemSelection: (TestDataModel) -> Unit,
) {
    val name = myTestDataItem.name
    val image = myTestDataItem.iconUrl
    val summary = myTestDataItem.summary
    val currentModel = myTestDataItem.eventModel.currentModel

    AnimatedVisibility(visible = useSpaceView) {
        Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
    }
    ListItem(name, image, summary, currentModel, ctaAction) {
        handleItemSelection(myTestDataItem)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ListItem(
    name: String,
    image: Int,
    summary: String,
    currentModel: CurrentModel,
    ctaAction: (CurrentModel) -> Unit,
    openBottomSheet: () -> Unit
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 2.dp),
        onClick = { openBottomSheet() },
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
        ) {
            PanelHeaderView(name, image)
            SummaryView(summary)
            CtaView(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.End),
                currentModel,
                ctaAction,
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun PanelHeaderView(testName: String, testImage: Int) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(0.1f),
            painter = painterResource(testImage),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = testName.isNotEmpty(),
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.8f)
                .padding(start = 20.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = testName,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
            )
        }
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color.Black
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SummaryView(summary: String) {
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = summary.isNotEmpty()) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp),
            factory = { context -> TextView(context) },
            update = { textView ->
                with(textView) {
                    text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(summary, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
                    setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))
                    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 60F)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CtaView(
    modifier: Modifier,
    currentModel: CurrentModel,
    ctaAction: (CurrentModel) -> Unit,
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        modifier = modifier,
        visible = currentModel.showCtaAction
    ) {
        ClickableText(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp),
            text = AnnotatedString(currentModel.actionTitle),
            onClick = { ctaAction(currentModel) }
        )
    }
}
```

I am using latest version of compose, you can find the [gradle.kt](https://github.com/vivek-modi/LazyColumn/blob/master/app/build.gradle)

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'

    def composeBom = platform "androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.05.01"
    implementation composeBom
    androidTestImplementation composeBom

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest"

    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.4.0"
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-workmanager:3.4.0"
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose:3.4.3"

}
```

**[MainActivity](https://github.com/vivek-modi/LazyColumn/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/lazycolumn/MainActivity.kt)**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
    private val viewModel by viewModel<MainActivityViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setupViewModel()
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    private fun setupViewModel() {
        viewModel.requestCompleteLiveData.observe(this) { dataReturned ->
            if (dataReturned) {
                setupView()
            }
        }

        viewModel.createData()
    }

    private fun setupView() {
        binding.composeView.setContent {
            AppBarScaffold(R.string.app_name, true) {
                SeeAllView(viewModel, {}, {})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the whole project in here [github](https://github.com/vivek-modi/LazyColumn/tree/master/app).

Thanks

Comment: Is the Samsung device you're testing on a low-end device? LazyRow/Column are known to suffer from some performance limitations. There was even recently an official Android Developers video where they suggested wrapping a RecyclerView in a Composable to avoid the issue.

Comment: @Tenfour04 what do you mean by low-end device ?

Comment: Can you show me which video is suggested wrap a recycler view in compose. I don't know about that. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I remembered wrong. This is definitely not an official recommendation! Here's the link: https://speakerdeck.com/louiscad/unusable-or-undebuggable-rebelling-against-best-practices

Comment: Low-end = not very powerful compared to the others. Slower CPU/GPU devices will show performance problems more obviously.

Comment: Thanks for sharing above information. The logic I tried in all samsung device. If device is slower `CPU/GPU` then it cause more scrolling issue.